# Display / Logic issue, Many-to-many, how to display?

Tags: php, many-to-many, mysqli, relational-database

i'm having a real problem here, i'm using php and mysql i designed a database for a music website.:

`artists` - `artist_id`, `artist_name`;

`tracks`  - `track_id`, `track_name`;

`ArtistTracks` - `track_id`, `artist_id` `// < no more than one row for any combination.`;

so i designed it and it's all good but now what if there a duet (to artists have the same track).

i'm so stupid that i just thought that i will solve this when i will add a duet.

so now i added a duet how do i display / select it.?

for example to get the latest tracks i do this.

```
        $sql = 'SELECT Tracks.track_id, Tracks.track_name, Artists.artist_name 

                   FROM ArtistTracks, Tracks, Artists

                WHERE ArtistTracks.track_id = Tracks.track_id
                AND ArtistTracks.artist_id = Artists.artist_id

                  ORDER BY tracks.track_id DESC LIMIT 10';
```

the result fair enough is like this:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [track_id] => 33
        [track_name] => track duet.
        [artist_name] => artist b
    )    

[1] => Array
    (
        [track_id] => 33
        [track_name] => track duet.
        [artist_name] => artist b
    )
```

my question is, did i did a mistake with the design of the database.???

and if not, how I'm suppose to display them do i need to loop over the whole array and check if the `track_id` match another `track_id` ??

thanks in advance for any help :\

**EDIT**

i have benn trying literally the whole day to find a solution that will be perfect, including droping the whole database and trying mongoDB LOLs,

i managed to make the tracks appear as the should `singer_one` and `singer_two` - `track_name`

the problem is that i had  6 templates for my whole website and now i have 12 (because there are two many conditionals)..

i dont like this solution because now i need to update any change in the site twice 
(because of the conditionals for displaying the duets.)

is my design of many-to-many wrong should i make another table for duets??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you must determine the side which has higher importance - probably artists (might be other way round in another page for example).

Your query makes little sense: you're completely missing the `JOIN` construct. Get your artists and join their songs. You may either use grouping and concatenate all songs for one artist into one field by using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) or not group the results and process the set with php (for every track it returns a row with artist name and track name).

**Grouping by artist:**

```
SELECT a.artist_name, GROUP_CONCAT(a.track_name SEPARATOR '; ') AS 'tracks' FROM artists a
    LEFT JOIN ArtistsTracks at ON at.artist_id = a.artist_id
    LEFT JOIN Tracks t ON at.track_id = t.track_id
    GROUP BY a.artist_id
```

**EDIT Grouping by track:**

```
SELECT a.track_name, GROUP_CONCAT(a.artist_name SEPARATOR '; ') AS 'artists' FROM artists a
    LEFT JOIN ArtistsTracks at ON at.artist_id = a.artist_id
    LEFT JOIN Tracks t ON at.track_id = t.track_id
    GROUP BY a.track_id
```

**Plain result:**

```
SELECT a.artist_name, a.track_name FROM artists a
    LEFT JOIN ArtistsTracks at ON at.artist_id = a.artist_id
    LEFT JOIN Tracks t ON at.track_id = t.track_id
```

Although the first two solutions run generally slower compared to the last one for large data-sets, you must account in the extra processing needed to be done by php for the last solution. Of course, if for example you want to link each track to its own page, you'd be better off with the last one. Just use one, which suits you the most.

Comment: i thought i knew how to select from MySQL, apparently i have some book reading to do.  thanks for your well explained answer.

Comment: The [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) explains joining quite well in my opinion. Good luck!

Comment: i'm sorry testing your solutions did not work as expected i'v edited my question for more information, i cant give up, i really need a hint of what i should do.

Comment: Well, first of all, what exactly do you want to do then. Do you want to have the results grouped by tracks or what?

Comment: i was processing the result set wrong with php, i tried another method and it works fine now. thanks.